# MPMoviePlayerController SWIFT video background not playing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I've been trying but my code isn't working. Does anybody know why? thanks.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!
    var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    moviePlayer!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)


    moviePlayer!.controlStyle = .None
    moviePlayer!.scalingMode = .AspectFill
    moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = .Unknown


    moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true
    moviePlayer!.play()

    self.view.insertSubview(moviePlayer.view, atIndex:0)

}
```

Comment: Quite a bit of information missing like: What do you expect it to do?  What isn't happening that you expect to happen?  What is happening that you expect to happen?  What have you done so far to isolate the problem?  What, if any, error messages are generated on the console?  In general [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I solved it. For some reason it is working with this code:

Comment: I was expecting a video playing at the background, I was seeing a black background instead. No errors in the console. I tried different snippets but none of them worked. Finally I solved it by using the following code...

Answer (score 1):

var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

```
    if let player = moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
        player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
        self.view.insertSubview(player.view, atIndex:0)
    }
```